# CPQ is creating amendment quotes as another user

Tags: quote, cpq

We have a custom trigger on the SBQQ Quote object that deletes the auto-generated opportunity and associates an existing opportunity to the newly created quote. This was working in the sandbox but not in production. We were getting the following error:

> "Can't save record. This record has been changed and saved in a
>   different session. Related the record and try again." Warning. Failed
>   to revert changes. Please check data integrity.

We also noticed that the quote wasn't created by the same user that amended the contract. It was created by the user that had been authorized in the CPQ configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that the sandbox was configured with **Use Legacy Amend/Renew Service** and production was not. After checking the Use Legacy Amend/Renew Service box in production the quote was not created as the user who initiated the quote and we no longer ran into the error.

To fix this:

1. Go to **Setup**
2. Navigate to the **Installed Packages** link
3. Go to CPQ and click on the **Configure** link
4. Click on the **Subscriptions and Renewals** tab
5. Check the Use **Legacy Amend/Renew Service** box
6. Click on the **Save** button